# Can we get previous versions of Windows 10 media creation tool?

Tags: windows, windows-10, media-creation-tool

If those previous versions actually download and install previous Windows 10 builds anyway... What I want to do is upgrade a computer which has build 1511, but I don't want it to be upgraded to 1709 (or Fall Creators update, if you prefer) because that build appears to be riddled with bugs (from my experience, anyway), but 1703 (Creators update) is fine by me, so I want this one. I already found how to get any ISO for any build version, but I would need to boot the computer with this and I can't because I don't have physical access to it (I access it remotely through TeamViewer, that's how we usually manage our users' computers) and that sort of operation is beyond the capabilities of most of our users. I know the media creation tool is capable of upgrading Windows 10 from within Windows itself, so is there a way to obtain a Windows 10 media creation tool that would install 1703 instead of 1709? Currently, the one that's easily found on Microsoft's website will only install 1709 and I don't want it.

Comment: So to clarify, you are willing to devote a tremendous amount of time and effort to avoiding Windows 10 version 1709 because in your opinion it is *"riddled with bugs."* Please elaborate: what type of bugs?

Comment: The worst one that led me to not want to install this version was with Windows update trying to install the same update over and over and always failing. The very same thing occurred on 3 different machines with a clean install. I had tried many solutions I had found online, such as trying Windows update troubleshooter and others I don't remember since that was several months ago. Also, the Settings window would crash often. I'm pretty sure there was something else, but I can't remember. I've never seen such abnormal behavior in 1703, so that's why I stuck with it.

Comment: [I posted how to get older ISOs](https://superuser.com/a/1108086/174557)

Comment: (There's a reason to want the Windows 7 version of the MCT: the one for Windows 10 is online-only (it actually crashes if it can't connect to the Internet, which is just bad programming, which isn't really a surprise from Microsoft these days ), so it's only capable of downloading the image to be used whereas the Windows 7 version allows you to specify the ISO to burn.)

Answer (score 3):

The tool has nothing to do with the content. The Media Creation Tool will download the latest ISO of Windows 10. There is no ability to select an older version of Windows.

Comment: While I agree with this answer.  I have also have a suspicion that due to `SetupMgr.dll` being packed into the executable in question, a specific version of the .XML file would attempt to be downloaded however, I also suspect the tool would attempt to update itself before it did so.  The tool has seen numerous improvements since it's first version and is the base for the Upgrade Assistance tool.

Answer (score 1):

> I know the media creation tool is capable of upgrading Windows 10 from within Windows itself, so is there a way to obtain a Windows 10 media creation tool that would install 1703 instead of 1709?

Even if you were to download an older version of the Media Creation Tool it would update itself and then download the current Windows 10 ISO.  Links to older versions of the [Media Creation Tool](http://download.microsoft.com/download/1/C/4/1C41BC6B-F8AB-403B-B04E-C96ED6047488/MediaCreationTool.exe) are incredibly easy to find though.  I was also able to find a [third-party source](http://www.filehorse.com/download-media-creation-tool/) for the 1703 tool which of course shouldn't be used due to the way the tool works.

> I already found how to get any ISO for any build version, but I would need to boot the computer with this.

This is incredibly false.  What you actually want to do is download the 1703 ISO, mount the ISO from within Windows, then start the upgrade from within Windows.  Booting to WinPE would only allow you to format the machine and reinstall Windows 10.

Booting to WinPE does not allow nor has it ever allowed you to upgrade an existing Windows installation.  This has been the case since Windows XP.

Perhaps understanding how the tool works will make it clear that mounting the ISO will result in the exact same process.

> 1. At first execution of MediaCreationTool.exe, it creates some folders
>      in System Drive like $Windows.~WS, $WINDOWS.~BT & ESD.
> 2. It downloads a Products_20170317.cab file from http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=841361 (for Creators Update). This link written in SetupMgr.dll file in that MediaCreationTool.exe (treated as .cab file). In that Products_20170317.cab file, there is a Products.xml file. Then it reads that XML file, find a ESD file link matching your language (like en-US for English), downloads that encrypted ESD file in C:\ESD folder.
> 3. After downloading the required ESD file, it reads the encryption key from Products.xml file to decrypt that ESD file. Now it converts ESD to ISO file.

All the tool does is download the appropriate ESD file and then converts it to an ISO.  After it converting it to an ISO, setup.exe is ran, and the upgrade is done in an identical process the `MediaCreationTool.exe` and `Windows10Upgrade9252.exe` uses to perform the upgrade.

Source: [Windows 10 Media Creation Tool, how does it work?](https://superuser.com/questions/1220373/windows-10-media-creation-tool-how-does-it-work/1220941#1220941)

Comment: I should be clear.  The link I provided isn't to 1703.  The version of the Media Creation Tool I linked to was designed to install 1511 and was before the tool was improved to support 1703 and 1709

Comment: I'll try mounting the ISO and do the upgrade from it, thanks a lot for the suggestion and information!

Answer (score 0):

I agree with you. Each new release of Windows 10 has consistently proven to be unsuitable for business machines. We consistently run one major version behind as each new release is loaded with bugs and compatibility issues as you have said. I like to be cutting edge but not bleeding edge.

Windows tries to update itself to the newest version. So, forget the tool, and use a more long term solution of putting your machines in the Current Branch for Business and/or deferring “Feature Updates” for a period of time.

This works on Professional, Enterprise and Education versions.

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/deployment/update/waas-manage-updates-wufb

However, if you have access to VLSC or possibly Technet/MSDN, you can download an .iso of any version of Windows 10 you want which is capable of upgrading a running system. Simply mount the .iso by double-clicking within Windows 10.