# How to do an in-place upgrade of Windows

Tags: windows, windows-10-upgrade, reinstall, windows-11-upgrade

A major advantage of doing an in-place upgrade compared to doing
a clean install,
is that all accounts, settings, and programs are kept intact.

##### *How can I do an in-place upgrade of Windows?*

The question concerns *non*-Enterprise editions only, and my primary
interest is in going from Windows 10 to Windows 10, using the
"upgrade" as a means to *repair* Windows.
<sup>1</sup>
I will welcome answers on upgrading to Windows 11 as well.
<sup>2</sup>

###### Motivation

At the time of writing, there are 160+ hits when running the query :
[https://superuser.com/search?q=is:a+[windows-10]+"in-place+upgrade"](https://superuser.com/search?tab=votes&q=is%3aa%20%5bwindows-10%5d%20%22in-place%20upgrade%22)

Quite a few of those answers advise to repair Windows by making
an *in-place upgrade*,
but I couldn't find a question on the topic.
This post aims to fill that gap by requesting a guide on *how* to
do it.

#### Caution!

*You must have at least 20 GiB free disk space on the Windows drive
to consider an in-place upgrade.*

#### References

- [Answers containing "in-place upgrade" | Windows 10](https://superuser.com/search?tab=votes&q=is%3aa%20%5bwindows-10%5d%20%22in-place%20upgrade%22)
- [Repair Install Windows 10 with an In-place Upgrade](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/16397-repair-install-windows-10-place-upgrade.html)
- [Repair Install Windows 11 with an In-place Upgrade](https://www.elevenforum.com/t/repair-install-windows-11-with-an-in-place-upgrade.418)

---

<sup>1</sup>
Possibly, but not necessarily, installing a newer build version.
For example, 21H2 → 22H2, or 22H2 → 22H2.

<sup>2</sup>
I expect the procedure for Windows 11 to be very similar
to that of Windows 10.

Answer (score 14):

> ##### *How can I do an in-place upgrade of Windows?*

When Windows Update failed, I salvaged the situation by making an
["in-place upgrade"](https://www.digitaltrends.com/computing/how-to-download-install-windows-10-iso/).
I didn't even need an installation DVD or a USB stick.
Nor the product key.
<sup>1</sup>
The procedure was pleasantly straightforward and mostly free from
obstacles.

I searched :
https://www.google.com/search?q=Download+%22Windows+10%22+media+creation+tool
which took me to :
[Download Windows 10 Disc Image (ISO File)](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/software-download/windows10).

I disregarded *Update now* and clicked *Download now* which
downloaded `MediaCreationTool22H2.exe`.

[image: The page 'Download Windows 10 Disc Image (ISO File)'.]

<sup>^ click to enlarge</sup>

Then I right-clicked `MediaCreationTool22H2.exe` and chose
*Run as administrator*.

[image: MediaCreationTool22H2.exe - Run as administrator.]

The first time I tried it, a window was shown, saying :
*There was a problem starting Setup. Close the tool, restart your PC,
and then try running the tool again.*

[image: Windows 10 Setup: 'There was a problem starting Setup'.]

Instead of restarting Windows, all I did was sign out and sign back
in again.
<sup>2</sup>
This time, I didn't get any error.

Then I was shown a window displaying
*Getting a few things ready*, and upon completion,
a license agreement, *Applicable notices and license terms*,
which I accepted.

[image: License agreement: 'Applicable notices and license terms'.]

The window *Getting a few things ready* was shown again.
I was then asked *What do you want to do?*, and given two options :

- Upgrade this PC now
- Create installation media (USB flash drive, DVD, or ISO file)
  for another PC

[image: Two options: I chose 'Upgrade this PC now'.]

The first option – *Upgrade this PC now* – was pre-chosen,
so I clicked <kbd>Next</kbd> to start the installation
of Windows 10, version 22H2.
Because of this choice, I never needed any USB stick.

The download took a little more than an hour (some 70 minutes).
When shown *Ready to install*, I left *Keep personal files and apps*
checked, and clicked *Install*.
The installation took about 16 hours.
<sup>3</sup>

[image: Windows 10 Setup: 'Ready to install'.]

#### The aftermath

I was slightly shocked that the installation took *sixteen* hours.
But putting that aside, compared to having *Windows Update* do a
version upgrade, this installation was quite smooth.
When Windows Update upgraded my Windows 10 from version 1803 to 21H2,
the *Windows modules installer worker* (`TiWorker.exe`) practically
hijacked my laptop for hours and hours, in the meanwhile making the
computer completely unusable.
<sup>4</sup>

One bad thing *did* happen the day after the upgrade – my disk usage
(HDD) went up to 100%, and stayed close to 100% for several hours.
This happened although the sum of the four most hungry processes
didn't even add up to 0.5 MB/s.
This normally results in no more than 5-10% disk usage – not anywhere
near 100%.
Weird.

[image: Hard disk: only 4 processes use 0.1 MB/s, yet 100% disk.]

I got fed up with it and performed the classical
Microsoft fix – "if in doubt, restart the PC".
Once restarted, the strange behavior was gone, and I haven't
seen it since.

---

Other than that, the registry was completely reset (which is *good*),
and that the annoying Microsoft Edge was installed (unfortunately).
<sup>5</sup>

I believe an in-place upgrade like this is possible,
*even if the current version of Windows 10 is the same* as the version
in [Windows 10 Disc Image (ISO File)](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/software-download/windows10).
<sup>6</sup>

#### Where are the installation files downloaded?

The Media Creation Tool
[saves the downloaded files to `C:\ESD\Windows`](https://superuser.com/a/1455179).
So if I want to do an in-place upgrade of the very same version
once more, then I don't need to download the files again.
Instead, I can just double-click `C:\ESD\Windows\setup.exe`.
When I did that, I was shown a window saying *Install Windows 10*.
And since I already had the latest drivers for my laptop, I clicked
*Change how Windows Setup downloads updates*.

[image: C:\ESD\Windows\setup.exe → 'Install Windows 10'.]

When shown *Get updates, drivers and optional features*, I clicked
*Not at the moment*, and then *Next*.

[image: Get updates, drivers … → 'Not at the moment'.]

Then the license terms were shown, and the rest was as above.
(I didn't complete it.)

#### What if the system doesn't boot?

Unfortunately, [if your system doesn't boot, you
cannot do an in-place upgrade, only a *clean install*](https://superuser.com/a/428525).
A clean install has many similarities with an in-place upgrade.
When reaching the window *What do you want to do?*, choose
*Create installation media …*,
and make sure to have a USB stick ready with a capacity
of at least 8 GB.
*All contents of that USB memory will be wiped out.*

Shut down the machine on which you want to clean install Windows.
When starting it, you need to change the boot order so that the
computer boots from the USB instead of from the hard drive.
On my *hp* laptop, this is done by repeatedly pressing the
<kbd>F9</kbd> key right after starting the computer.

The option *OS boot Manager (UEFI)* was pre-chosen, so I used the
down-arrow (<kbd>↓</kbd>)
on my keyboard to mark *USB Hard Drive (UEFI)*,
and then pressed <kbd>Enter</kbd>.
I didn't continue, but instructions should follow on how to proceed
with the installation.

### References

- [How to download a Windows 10 ISO file and install Windows](https://www.digitaltrends.com/computing/how-to-download-install-windows-10-iso/)
- [Download page for Windows 10 Disc Image (ISO File)](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/software-download/windows10)
- [How to completely uninstall Microsoft Edge](https://superuser.com/a/1750952)
- [Media Creation Tool saves its downloaded files to `C:\ESD`](https://superuser.com/a/1455179)
- [An Upgrade needs a booting system to work](https://superuser.com/a/428525)
- [Another link on how to do an in-place upgrade](https://www.makeuseof.com/tag/windows-10-wont-boot/#repair-update-quot-in-place-upgrade-quot)

---

<sup>1</sup>
In case you *do* need the product key,
press <kbd>WinKey</kbd>+<kbd>r</kbd>, type `cmd`,
and press <kbd>Enter</kbd> to open a command line window.
Copy-paste
`wmic path SoftwareLicensingService get OA3xOriginalProductKey`.
Press <kbd>Enter</kbd>.

<sup>2</sup>
To sign out, press <kbd>WinKey</kbd>+<kbd>x</kbd>, <kbd>u</kbd>,
<kbd>i</kbd>.

<sup>3</sup>
Yes – *sixteen* hours.
But the result was a shiny new installation of Windows 10,
version 22H2.

<sup>4</sup>
As I recall it, it wasn't just hours, more like *days*.
Extremely frustrating.

<sup>5</sup>
I've since written
[a guide on how to get rid of Microsoft Edge](https://superuser.com/a/1750952).

<sup>6</sup>
I haven't tried it, though.
To be picky, if the version to be installed is the same as the
version already running, then it's a *reinstall*, not an upgrade.

Comment: Logging out and logging back in also works to resolve issue of black screen after windows 11 update. You can CTRL-ALT-DEL and sign out there.